# Force text onto next line

Tags: vb.net, .net-2.0

I have a text file with data pieced together needs to be separated onto separate lines. Not sure how to go about doing it, still new to vb.

I'm thinking about something along the lines of:

```
                If sLine.EndsWith(", ") Then
                  "Do Something"
                End If
```

Answer (score 0):

So for anyone wondering if they come across this post, I'm new to vb.net so I'm still discovering all sorts of tricks to the language. One such "trick" resolved this issue, and that is that you can use the carriage return from VB6 (vbCr). This separated all of the criteria I needed set to the next line, thus, resolving the issue for me.

So this line of code:

```
subchild = subchild.Replace(", '", vbCr)
```

Would turn this:

```
ABCDEFG, HIJKLMN, OPQRSTU
```

Into this:

```
ABCDEFG
HIJKLMN
OPQRSTU
```